# How to Send POST method with multipart request using CAMEL

Tags: apache-camel, multipart

How to Send POST method with multipart request using CAMEL

I have an application with camel setup and i need to attach documents and send and HTTP POST request.

How can i do this,

Answer (score 0):

You can always write some java code with the apache httpcompenents library. see http://hc.apache.org/

It is not difficult to use